# Allow edit of Model based on a set permission as well as Model's property value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a Location Model, which contains two properties: ID and Name.

To edit this Model, I have set up this route:

```
Route::get('administration/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit');
```

I set up very simple permissions: In the `AuthServiceProvider` I am checking in the `boot` method the following

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $permission) {
    if ($user->permissions->pluck('name')->contains($permission)) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Where `permission` is a Model that contains an ID and a name, mapped via a `permission_user` table.

I have these permissions set up:

- edit_los_angeles
- edit_new_york
- edit_boston
- plenty_of_other_permissions_not_related_to_location

After all this rambling, my actual question:

**How can I tie these permissions to the edit the location?**

The problem that I am facing is, that a given user is not allowed to edit all locations but may only be allowed to edit one location. Only the user with permission `edit_los_angeles` would be allowed to edit the `Location` with the name `Los Angeles`.
So I cannot group this into one permission like `edit_location` and add this to my route `->middleware('can:edit_location')`.

Instead, I would need something like this, I guess:

```
Route::get('administration/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit')->middleware('can:edit_los_angeles');
Route::get('administration/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit')->middleware('can:edit_new_york');
Route::get('administration/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit')->middleware('can:edit_boston');
```

...obviously this would not work.

What would be your approach to tackle this dilemma? :-)
Maybe I am doing something completely wrong and there is a better Laravel-Way of doing this?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

I am using Laravel 6.0 :-)

Comment: I guess location is a model?

Comment: Yes, Location is a Model :-)

Comment: I think there is a more generic solution will write a solution tonight.

Comment: Thanks @mrhn looking forward to it :-)

Comment: is there any binding between location and permissions or can you derive em from the name?

Comment: I was thinking that I could maybe add a unique slug to the location, e.g. `los-angeles`. Otherwise there would be no binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two assumption for my approach to work, use model binding in the controller (you should do that no matter what). Secondly there needs to be a relation between location and the permission it needs, something similar to the slug you suggested.

Your controller function would look something like this. Adding a FormRequest is a good approach for doing this logic.

```
class LocationController {
     public function edit(EditLocationRequest $request, Location $location) { // implicit model binding
         ...
     }
}
```

For ease of use, i would also make a policy.

```
class LocationPolicy
{
    public function edit(User $user, Location $location) {
        return $user->permissions->pluck('name')
            ->contains($location->permission_slug); // assuming we have a binding
    }
}
```

Remember to register policy in the `AuthServiceProvider.php`.

```
protected $policies = [
    Location::class => LocationPolicy::class,
];
```

Now in your form request consume the policy in the authorize method. From here you are in a request context, you can access user on `$this->user()` and you can access all models that are model binding on their name for example `$this->location`.

```
class EditLocationRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return $this->user()->can('edit', $this->location);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to only have a single route definition.

```
Route::get('administration/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit');
```

**EDIT**

Withouth the form request if you use the trait AuthorizesRequests you can do the following. This will throw an AuthorizationException of it fails.

```
use AuthorizesRequests;

public function edit() {
    $this->authorize('edit', $location);
}
```

Comment: I know this is a little far out from your original idea with gates, but this is how i would do it and here you do not need multiple route definitions

Comment: Wow, I just learned so much from this post! Thank you very much @mrhn ! I will give this a try tomorrow. Have a great rest of your Sunday :-)

Comment: Would you recommend creating a form request with `php artisan make:request` to create `EditLocationRequest` or should it rather be named `LocationRequest`? Not sure what the correct convention is.

Comment: I would also go with the controller method name + LocationRequest. So if you method name is edit, call it EditLocationRequest. I don't think there is a standard per say

Comment: Thank! I will go with `EditLocationRequest` :-)

Comment: Is there a way to extend this, so I can use the `@can` directive in a blade view, e.g. `@can('los_angeles', $location)`?

Comment: Wow, nevermind. It already does. Thank you very much for this great example of how to use policies and form requests! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem mate, this is in my opinion a really clean way to achieve it

Comment: I agree, this is great! What would the cleanest solution be to call this logic from the location controller's update method? Would I create a UpdateLocationRequest? Seems a bit redundant, right? There is probably a better way :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a requirement based upon the location relationship, then you will need to capture that relationship in the data. A good starting point to this would be to add a pivot table specific for these editing permissions. Consider a table, `location_permissions`, with a `user_id` and a `location_id`. You could then modify or add permission middleware to do a check for a record in this table once you have a specific user and location.

Edit: to answer the question about implementation of middleware,

The crux of the implementation would likely be solved by defining a relationship on the user model to location via this new pivot table.

I would recommend then adding an additional method which consumes the new `locations` relationship to the model along the lines of

```
public function canEditLocation(Location $location): bool { 

   return $this->locations
               ->where('location_id', '=', $location->id)
               ->count() > 0; 
    }
```

And the actual middleware something along these lines:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $location)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->canEditLocation($location)) {
            \\handle failed permission as appropriate here.
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

My middleware parameters knowledge is rusty, but I believe that is correct as defined at https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: What would the added permission middleware look like? :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give this approach a try :-)    Where would you add the canEditLocation method? To the Location model itself?

Comment: I think it makes sense to add it directly to the model, yes. Glad to hear this helps!

Comment: Great! Again, thank you very much for your help :-)